# Refatorar código usando LINQ no C#

Tags: c#, linq, refatoração

preciso refatorar esse método em `C#` e substituir esses 3 foreach por algo menor usando `LINQ`:

```
    public List<Ponto> Filtrar(IQueryable<Ponto> pontosFiltrados, List<Usuario> usuarios)
    {
        var pontosFiltradosPorUsuarios = new List<Ponto>();
        var cont = 0;

        foreach (var ponto in pontosFiltrados)
        {
            foreach (var usuario in usuarios)
            {
                foreach (var pontoUsuario in ponto.Usuarios)
                {
                    if (pontoUsuario.Id == usuario.Id)
                    {
                        cont++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (cont == usuarios.Count && ponto.Usuarios.Count == usuarios.Count)
            {
                pontosFiltradosPorUsuarios.Add(ponto);
            }

            cont = 0;
        }

        return pontosFiltradosPorUsuarios;
    }
```

O que esse método precisa fazer é retornar todos os pontos que tenham exatamente a lista de usuários passado como argumento.

As classes **Usuário** e **Ponto** estão abaixo:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}

public class Ponto
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventualmente haverá outra forma de o fazer (o que é normal em LINQ), mas aqui vai uma solução:

```
public List<Ponto> Filtrar(IQueryable<Ponto> pontosFiltrados, List<Usuario> usuarios)
{
    return pontosFiltrados
        .Where(r => r.Usuarios.Count == usuarios.Count && r.Usuarios
            .All(x => usuarios
                .Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)))
        .ToList();
}
```